# Firebase and table view duplicating data swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I use firebase database and table view. I put there an object. The code:

```
thingManager.addNewThing(thingName.text!)
let thingRef = self.thingsRef.childByAppendingPath(thingName.text!)
thingRef.setValue(thingManager.toAnyObject(thingName.text!)
```

All of the elements from database are displayed in table view. Table view is loaded everytime the application starts.

I load the table view by having an array from which table view takes info. Everytime the app is loaded, the array is filled with elements from database.

The problem is that the elements duplicates in table view when I add new object to the database. The data doesn't duplicate in the database itself, but it duplicates somewhere in that array. Tried multiple things and when I delete the last two lines

```
let thingRef = self.thingsRef.childByAppendingPath(thingName.text!)
thingRef.setValue(thingManager.toAnyObject(thingName.text!)
```

everything works fine, but the data is now not saved in the database. My question is: can these two lines cause the duplication? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to sync the table view?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I was loading the Firebase Data into a GLOBAL Array of structs. I was able to fix my issue by switching the Array to a LOCAL array in my tableView class. Let me know if this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

your code is not very clear, but i think you need

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self.YourTableView.reloadData()
})
```